# How to call Go program from varnish subroutine

Tags: go, varnish, varnish-vcl

Say "I'm running varnish and I want to call Go code from varnish subroutines". that will run for every `vcl_recv` subroutine?

Comment: you probably need to look at https://github.com/phenomenes/vago

Comment: not satisfy my needs I've seen it before i want to some how call my go lang function from varnish subroutine to normalize lat Lon based on quad tree algorithm

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather form the Varnish docs, an official way to have [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) in Varnish is using [VMODs](https://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Appendix_D__VMOD_Development.html) — **V**arnish **Mod**ules.

It appears to be presupposed one uses C to write VMODs (maybe with the little help of `vmodtool.py` which is able to translate VCC to plain C).

Still, you could explore two approaches to hook Go into that mix:

- Compile your Go code using the [`-buildmode=c-shared`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_modes) mode to produce a `.so` file with the C-compatible interface.

  This approach will create a "free-standing" Varnish module,
  which does not rely on `libc`, just exports a C-compatible API from the library.

  But while this is doable, you'd need to "mirror" certain data structures provided by Varnish and maybe you'll need to call *into* Varnish API back from your module.
  So the next approach seems to be more feasible.
- Use [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) to wire up your Go code with C API exported by Varnish. You will supposedly still need to use `-buildmode=c-shared`.

All-in-all, you'd better first play with the native VMODs as documented in the Varnish book I linked to.

---

I'd also make the following minor points:

- I have no personal experience with VMODs.
  It's quite possible they're supposed to be linked-in statically when building Varnish from the source.

  If so, you'd need to use `-buildmode=c-archive`.
- It appears that doing what you're after would be an uphill
  battle for you, so I'd seriously consider porting whatever algorithm you have implemented in Go to that Varnish-specific VCC.

Comment: What if I make my go code an http service can I make http request in varnish subroutine?

Comment: That is certainly doable but this will obviously incur certain latency to processing each request (round-trip to your service in addition to processing time done there), so the answer is "it depends on the requirements".